# Margin to other Views in RelativeLayout not working

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I currently have a problem with one of my `Android` views.

I'm using a `NavigationDrawer` and know I'm not able to use margin in my `RelativeLayout` to get a space between elements

```
    <!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.cardio.MainActivity" >

    <!--
         As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
    -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/hersteller"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/modell"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/hersteller"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:longClickable="false" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/preisSB"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/modell"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/preisET"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/preisSB"
            android:layout_below="@id/modell"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp" />

        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/leistung"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/preisSB"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
    <!--
         android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
    -->
    <!--
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container.
    -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:background="#FFFF10"
        android:name="com.example.cardio.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I already have other layout which looks mostly similar, but I can't find a reason why my new one doesn't work.

Hope you guys can help me.

That's how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what the screen looks like now, and what should it look like.

Comment: i'm not allowed to post a screenshot :D but too make it a bit more clear. What i want is that the margin of 150dp i have in my EditText 'leistung' is to the SeekBar and not to the start of my screen, as it is now

Comment: Edited a link to the screenshot in the question

Comment: Solved it by removing the alignParentTop attribute